# How to set up Spring Boot + Bitronix + non-XA Datasource + XA JMS Connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jta, bitronix

I'm trying to set-up Bitronix in Spring Boot to use last resource gambit with non-XA datasource. Of course by default (autoconfiguration) data source does not participate in XA transaction.
It seems that `org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper` will work only for `XADataSource`.

How to connect `DataSource` with Bitronix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitronix uses its [`LrcXADataSource`](https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm/src/main/java/bitronix/tm/resource/jdbc/lrc/LrcXADataSource.java) to implement the last resource gambit. You need to tell Spring Boot to create an `XAResource` of that type:

```
spring.datasource.xa.data-source-class-name=bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource
```

You'll also need to set some other properties that will depend on the database you're using and how it's configured. For example, the name of the JDBC driver class:

```
spring.datasource.xa.properties.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

Comment: And then `org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper` will wrap it up with Bitronix's connection pool `org.springframework.boot.jta.bitronix.PoolingDataSourceBean`, right?

Comment: But what happens if I have 2 Non-XA Datasources?

Comment: @ElLordCode The last resource gambit only works with a single non-XA DataSource

Comment: Is there any solution if need more than one Non-XA Datasources in my Bitronix server?